# Can't write on phone memory on Android 6

Tags: android, file, memory, ioexception, file-access

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
  <permission
    android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

And this is the Error I get in logcat:

```
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348): java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at nl.hgrams.passenger.utils.Utils.appendLog(Utils.java:829)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at nl.hgrams.passenger.PSLocationCenter.onCreate(PSLocationCenter.java:233)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 12-02 10:03:30.532: W/System.err(11348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 12-02 10:03:30.533: W/System.err(11348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 12-02 10:03:30.533: W/System.err(11348): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 12-02 10:03:30.533: W/System.err(11348):   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
 12-02 10:03:30.533: W/System.err(11348):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
 12-02 10:03:30.533: W/System.err(11348):   at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
 12-02 10:03:30.533: W/System.err(11348):   ... 12 more
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Passenger/passenger_log.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:58)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at nl.hgrams.passenger.utils.Utils.writeToLog(Utils.java:905)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at nl.hgrams.passenger.utils.Utils.appendLog(Utils.java:849)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at nl.hgrams.passenger.PSLocationCenter.onCreate(PSLocationCenter.java:233)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 12-02 10:03:30.535: W/System.err(11348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
 12-02 10:03:30.536: W/System.err(11348):   ... 15 more
```

I found that I need to do this, to declare them in api 23+:

```
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
 };
```

but it doens't recognise the permissions if I set them like that.

`cannot resolve symbol Manifest.permission.Read/Write...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

public class ClassName {

private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    public void requestPermissions(Activity activity) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

source http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html

user needs to provide permissions manually by going into settings-> apps-> app_name-> permission or you have to manually ask for permissions during the application runtime programmatically.

Comment: I tried the code from there and it says for:

     Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Unresolved symbol. Even if I have it in my Manifest. only permission that appears is MAPS_RECEIVE. Do I also need to make this for the other permissions?

<permission
    android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Comment: Had to add the permissions like this, so they are visible:
  <permission
        android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:protectionLevel="signature" />